# Solving integral $\int \frac{3x-1}{\left(x^2+16\right)^3}$

Tags: integration

I need to solve this one integral. 
$$\int \frac{3x-1}{\left(x^2+16\right)^3}$$

You need to use the method of undetermined coefficients. That's what I get:

[image]
[image]

$$(3x-1) = (Ax + B)(x^{2}+16)^{2} + (Cx + D)(x^{2}+16) + (Ex + F)$$
$$1: 256B + 16D + F = -1$$
$$x: 256A + 16C + E = 3$$
$$x2: 32B + D = 0$$
$$x3: 32A + C = 0$$
$$x4: B = 0$$
$$x5: A = 0$$

$$A = 0;B = 0;C = 0;D = 0;E = 3;F = -1;$$
[image]

It turns out that I'm back to the same integral. What is wrong I do?

Comment: When i see the expansion in your first line it's no surprise  that you get the same integral, because the third term is of the form of the original integral. what else should happen ?

Comment: @tired Tell me how.

Comment: Try using partial fractions. And don't forget  " $dx$" :P

Comment: the point is, that your integral is already maximally decomposed, at least if you don't want to introduce complex numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your integrand is already decomposed in partial fractions, start with the next step. The derivative of $x^2 + 16$ is $2x$, hence we have
$$ \int \frac{3x-1}{(x^2+ 16)^3}\, dx = \frac 32 \int\frac{2x}{(x^2 +16)^3}\,dx -\int\frac{1}{(x^2+16)^3}\, dx $$
In the first term, let $u = x^2+16$, giving
$$ \int \frac{2x}{(x^2+16)^3}\, dx = \int u^{-3}\, du = -\frac 12 u^{-2} 
   = -\frac 1{2(x^2 + 16)^2} $$
In the second term, we let $v = \frac x4$, giving
$$ \int \frac{1}{(x^2 + 16)^3}\, dx = 4\int \frac{1}{(16v^2 + 16)^3}\, dv
  = \frac 1{1024}\int \frac{dv}{(v^2 + 1)^3} $$
Now we have by partial integration that 
$$ \int \frac{dv}{(v^2 + 1)^\alpha} = \frac{v}{2(\alpha-1)(v^2+ 1)^{\alpha - 1}} + \frac{2\alpha -3}{2\alpha - 2}\int \frac{dv}{(v^2 + 1)^{\alpha -1}} $$
Hence
\begin{align*}
  \int \frac{dv}{(v^2 + 1)^3} &= \frac v{4(v^2 + 1)^2} + \frac{3}4 \int \frac {dv}{(v^2 + 1)^2}\\
    &= \frac v{4(v^2 + 1)^2} + \frac 34 \cdot \frac{v}{2(v^2 + 1)} + \frac 34 \cdot \frac 12 \int \frac{dv}{v^2 + 1} \\
    &= \frac v{4(v^2 + 1)^2} +\frac{3v}{8(v^2 + 1)} + \frac 38 \arctan v 
\end{align*}
Let $v = \frac x4$ again and you are done.

Comment: Thank you. BUT!
You need to use the method of undetermined coefficients.

Comment: You have already computed the partial fraction decomposition. This fraction cannot by decomposed any more. Go on to the next step ... integrate ... see above!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Alternately, evaluate $I(a)~=~\displaystyle\int\frac{3x-1}{x^2+a}~dx$ assuming $a>0$, and then try to express your integral in terms of $I''(16)$.