# Evaluate $\int \frac{dx}{(x^2 + 1)^\alpha}$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I couldn't follow a step while reading this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1237316/135088). Since I do not have enough reputation to post this as a comment, I'm asking a question instead. The answer uses "partial integration" to write this $$ \int \frac{dv}{(v^2 + 1)^\alpha} = \frac{v}{2(\alpha-1)(v^2+ 1)^{\alpha - 1}} + \frac{2\alpha -3}{2\alpha - 2}\int \frac{dv}{(v^2 + 1)^{\alpha -1}} $$
I would like to know what this technique is, and how this equality follows from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Partial integration" just means integration by parts. The important step here is the writing of the fraction as
$$ \frac{1}{(v^2+1)^{\alpha}} = \frac{1}{(v^2+1)^{\alpha}} - \frac{1}{(v^2+1)^{\alpha-1}} + \frac{1}{(v^2+1)^{\alpha-1}} \\
= -\frac{v^2}{(v^2+1)^{\alpha}} + \frac{1}{(v^2+1)^{\alpha-1}}. $$
Then you integrate the first term by parts, integrating $\frac{v}{(v^2+1)^{\alpha}}$ and differentiating $v$; this gives
$$ \int \left( \frac{1}{(v^2+1)^{\alpha}}-\frac{1}{(v^2+1)^{\alpha-1}} \right) \, dv = -\int \frac{v^2}{(v^2+1)^{\alpha}} \, dv \\
= \frac{v}{2(\alpha-1)(v^2+1)^{\alpha-1}} - \frac{1}{2(\alpha-1)}\int \frac{dv}{(v^2+1)^{\alpha-1}},  $$
and then rearranging gives the result.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I thought partial integration meant integration by parts but couldn't come up with this manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

Try integration by parts
$$f= (v^2+1)^{-\alpha} ; g' =1 \\
f'=(-\alpha) (v^2+1)^{-\alpha-1}(2v) ; g=v$$

**P.S.** After integration by Parts, you write the $v^2$ in the numerator as 
$$v^2=(v^2+1)-1$$
and split the integral in two.